# Switch off android word suggestions for web input type=text

Tags: android, html

I have a .html file with an input control of type=text which is for the user to make random input that do not make up a dictionary word.  It is not inside a form.  It is not a password field.

```
<input id="myblah" type="text" placeholder="hello" name="s" size="20" 
maxlength="36"  autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" 
spellcheck="false"/>
```

On an Android phone, when I browse to the .html file and type in text into this input control the keyboard software makes suggestions and sometimes "corrects" the input to a word.  This is behaviour that I would like to switch off - from what I've read, the above attributes should switch it off, so I'm at a bit of a loss.

(Latest version of android on a Samsung Galaxy S3, using the dolphin browser and swiftkey-x keyboard)

Comment: `autocapitalize="off"` is deprecated, change for `autocapitalize="none"`. But SwiftKey keyboard ignores those attributes, so it won't work anyway. Should work fine on Google keyboard and Apple keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as autocapitalize(from what I know of html), but you might be able to try this. `<input id="myblah" type="text" placeholder="hello" name="s" size="20" 
maxlength="36" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" />`

I am not too sure whether or not this will work on android for I do not have an Android Smartphone but this works on my browser.

Answer (score 0):

For input controls:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"
    class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your user name" 
    value="" 
    autocapitalize="off" 
    autocomplete="off"
    spellcheck="false" 
    autocorrect="off"   />
```

For a textarea control:

```
<textarea type="text" name="control_codes" id="control_codes"
    class="form-control" placeholder="Enter device control codes"  
    autocapitalize="off"
    autocomplete="off"
    spellcheck="false"
    autocorrect="off">
</textarea>
```